# port forwarding in windows 7 to vmware

Tags: virtual-machine, port-forwarding, vmware-workstation, nat

I have a windows 7 in a network with ip 10.1.1.74 and I have vmware with centos which it's ip is 192.168.160.129 and has configured as NAT with my local windows 7. I have set up a apache httpd server on my centos which is listening on port 80 and there a project running in this httpd server. Now I want to see this httpd server from other computers in this network (10.1.1.x). what should I do?

Comment: You would need to put your VM live on port 80 and connect to it through your external IP. You do this via your router.

Comment: Since you are using your computer as a router (with the NAT setup), you need your computer to do the port forwarding. If VMWare doesn't support this function (I can't tell, I use VirtualBox), you need 3rd party routing software on your Windows 7 computer. You can check out http://www.simpleportforwarding.com/, or use Google to find something else you may prefer. Once this has been set up, other computers connect to your Windows 7 ip, e.g. on port 8080, and your Windows 7 will forward it to your Centos port 80.

Comment: The other solution is to change your NAT network to a Bridged network and put everything on the same subnet... This may be a problem if you connect to different networks.